# variables not getting replaced inside the text read from file- Korn shell

Tags: unix, ksh

It should be a simple error. But unable to resolve with multiple tries.

Using unix Korn shell I want to read an sql file into a unix ksh variable.(file is properly indented(formatted)). Along with that i want to resolve all the $variables inside the sql text.

below is the command which reads the file as is. The query.sql file(actual file is bigger and has more variables) has `$MONTH` and `$YEAR` and i want the actual value be replaced in the qry.

`IFS` is used to avoid removing the line breaks. Below is a testable ksh code

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh
    createqry()
    {
       MONTH=$1
       YEAR=$2
       IFS=
       qry=$(cat query.sql)
       echo $qry
   }
   QRY=$(createqry $month,$year)
   #write the QRY to file
   echo "$QRY" > outputqry.sql
```

For eg:`query.sql`

```
Select * from table where trans_month=$MONTH and trans_Year=$YEAR
```

The `outputqry.sql` should be

```
Select * from table where trans_month=10 and trans_Year=2017
```

For downvote's - I have searched in Google and SO with the same problem and could not resolve it. Hence the post

Comment: `IFS` is incredibly tricky to use correctly.  Sometimes, it's the only way, I know, but it has a high surprise rate.  Get it as close to the line of code where you need it, then restore it to the default as soon after as you can manage.  In any case, please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of what's failing - it should include your `IFS` line.

Comment: In the GNU package gettext you find `envsubst`. According to your `ksh` tag the following answer is not fit:  `qry=$(envsubst <query.sql)`. It is interesting for other readers using bash.

Comment: @Mike Andrews: modified the code , it can be tested as is

Comment: @Mike Andrews without IFS all line breaks are removed in the output sql

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is for the `$MONTH` and `$YEAR` references to be evaluated and while that's doable, you then run into the issue that the `*` will also be evaluated (eg, `*` is replaced with the name of every file in the current directory).

Someone else can jump in with a solution on if/how to evaluate the variables but not the asterisk ... while I'm going to propose a different approach ... something I routinely do when I want to pass variables into a template *sql script.

The first step is to reformat the template script, using names as place holders which also serve as invalid identifiers to the db engine (eg, keeps the template script from running in the database unless the place holders have been properly replaced).  Something like:

```
$ cat query.sql
Select * from table where trans_month=MONTH and trans_Year=YEAR
```

Assuming we have the current variable assignments ...

```
$ YEAR=10 MONTH=2018
```

You now have a few options for replacing the `MONTH` and `YEAR` placeholders depending on your shell (and version) and your preference for commands.  A couple examples:

```
# disable expansion of '*'

$ set -f

# let 'sed' replace place holders with variable values;
# make sure you use double quotes around the 'sed' patterns
# to ensure the variables are evaluated

$ x=$(sed "s/MONTH/${MONTH}/g ; s/YEAR/${YEAR}/g" query.sql)

# let's see what we got

$ echo "${x}"
Select * from table where trans_month=10 and trans_Year=2014
```

With `bash` you can use process substitution if you prefer:

```
$ set -f

$ read x < <(sed "s/MONTH/${MONTH}/g ; s/YEAR/${YEAR}/g" query.sql)

$ echo "${x}"
Select * from table where trans_month=10 and trans_Year=2014
```

Comment: Thank you. This find replace method also looks fine for me.Ill test if the line breaks would also stay intact.  Just another thought - What if i use a $star  as a placeholder in query.sql and replace it in code as $star="*". Does it work?  Because in my actual query i have more than 2 variables. so using sed, it gets lengthy

Answer (score 0):

It would have been easier when  all variables in `query.sql` were enclosed in curly braces like `${month}`. When you include the braces in the matching pattern, you do not have to worry about `$year` and `$yearly`. I have added `sort -r` trying to work-around the variables.
I needed a character unknown in the variables for constructing a sed command. I used the `=` and omitted the variables that have one (resulting in two `=`s in the `env` output).
You tagged the question with `ksh`, so the following (with process substitution) will not work:

```
sed -f <(env | grep -Ev "=.*="| sort -r | sed -r 's/(.*)=(.*)/s=$\1=\2=g/') query.sql
```

In POSIX you need

```
env | grep -Ev "=.*="| sort -r | sed -r 's/(.*)=(.*)/s=$\1=\2=g/' > /tmp/srd.wrk
sed -f /tmp/srd.wrk query.sql
```